# FileNotFoundException - Dynamic Discovery

Tags: c#, exception, testing

Fairly simple question I'm hoping but I've not managed to find an answer yet on Google that works...

I'm working in a C# testing context, and am referencing a managed C++ DLL which then references normal C++ assemblies. When I try to run my test I get a FileNotFoundException that doesn't give me any details on the file it was unable to find.

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The specified module could not be
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

I've done some checking with ProcMon and found it's trying to load up one of the C++ DLL's but it's probing all the standard places (C:\Windows, C:\Windows\System etc..). Is there a way I can redirect this to include an additional folder where all our binaries are built to?

I'm guessing there's something on the AppDomain but I've not quite figured out which property to use, which will work.

Comment: Have you tried to go into the properties and set the C++ dll to copy local and or have you tried to GAC or add the reference to the .dll thru the designer..?

Comment: I can't change the C++ Dll and don't really want it in the GAC... sorry

Comment: I've seen this type of thing in deployments when the appropriate C++ runtime library is not installed. Are you able to load and execute the unmanaged C++ DLL(s) directly, i.e., from a native C++ application?

Comment: You could pinvoke SetDllDirectory()

Comment: @HansPassant : You should post that as an answer. It seems to have worked for the first hurdle :) Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [best solution to use a DLL/Driver?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333434/best-solution-to-use-a-dll-driver)

Comment: Hmm, similar answer but I think the question has some merit for others who are having a similar problem as it's easier to search for, especially if I include the full error message which I'll add in now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Hans suggestions:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetDllDirectory(string lpPathName);

SetDllDirectory(@"C:\SomeDir");
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add that path to the `Path` environment variable.

**In Windows 7:** Press the windows key, type 'environment', select `Edit the system environment variables`, select `Environment variables`... add path...

**Programmatically:** See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185208/how-do-i-get-and-set-environment-variables-in-c).

But I think a more common approach is to copy the referenced DLLs to your output directory. Even if this requires more disk space, it guarantees that the referenced DLLs are always compatible with your C# application. If the DLLs change by a CVS update, and you don't rebuild your C# application, it will probably not start as expected.

Comment: Probably will work, but is it possible to do so via C# instead? I don't want to have to tell the entire Dev team to update their environment variables if possible...

Comment: @lan: edited post. Nevertheless I don't think this is the better solution. What if one developer has the dlls on `D:\yourpath` instead of `C:\yourpath`?

Comment: Also this post is to change the environment variables... Thinking about it this may stuff up the duplicates of the items in the GAC already.

Comment: I've tried the latter, but unfortunately the testing output directory isn't probed, that's what I'm trying to fix.